# Overflow icon is not changing in actionbarsherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the overflow icon in action bar.I am using ActionBarSherlock and I have used following styles to replace the default overflow icon:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">

        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverFlow</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverFlow</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme.OverFlow" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light</item>
    </style>
```

But the above code is not working and still showing me the default gray color icon.But the drawable I have mentioned above is of white color.Please guide me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What is `android:theme` set as in your manifest?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light`

to

`@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark`

and you will get the "white" overflow icons.

Comment: @drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light image already exists in my hdpi folder and is white in color.Do you think still I need to make changes that you have mentioned?

Comment: I would definitely try! I had to make this change yesterday and I changed `light` to `dark` and it worked.